# Legend titles in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble with the titles in my legend in the Blockbuilder below.

This snippet defines the scale used for the legend titles:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Pass", "Fail", "No Data"])
    .range(["green", "red", "black"]);
```

However, I can't get them to display correctly.

Here is the link to the [Blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/adamfknapp/c5cd902b20ea87b35e420f26f016e8f5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the scale's range, pass its domain:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                     
    .data(color.domain())  
    .enter()                                                
    .append('g');
```

Here is the updated blockbuilder: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/4779ee79f034c443ac0119cf26bc5392